# exec a string encoded in utf-8 in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I'm trying to use the exec function to run python code that I read out of a file that I know is encoded in utf-8. I've tried using string encode and decode, but it deletes the " and ' characters. How do I convert it to ascii for the purposes of exec without losing characters?

```
command = os.popen("tesseract img/" + image + " stdout","r")
code = command.readline()
print(code)
exec("# coding=utf-8\n" + code)
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Also, an example of your file's contents.

Comment: Are you reading the file correctly in the first place (are you specifying an encoding option to the open() method you're using)?

Comment: `print(repr(code))` and post that pls

Comment: Give code that reproduces the error.  Read this: [mcve].  If `code` is actually correctly UTF-8-encoded, it should work.